# "Add Comment" button is gone on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

As Kasra has resolved issue and posted answer, I tried to post a comment on the answer and app was crashed.

I tried to reproduce the issue, but not able to find out the exact issue, but still something weird is happening: "*Add Comment*" button has gone.

[image: no "Add Comment"!]

Comment: It looks like a candidate for [meta-tag:status-norepo] :(

Comment: I reproed this, but it's being a little harder to track down than I expected. Will fix soon.

Comment: I flagged this as "no repro" on v1.0.83. There are also many changes between these version (v.0.x to v1.0.83), including Q&A renewal page (v1.0.67) and comment contextual toolbar. If it's still repro'd on your side, please update the details. Otherwise, might be dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260393/add-comment-button-in-android-app-disappears-after-pressing-the-button-on-diff