# 'Add comment' button in Android app disappears after pressing the button on different posts consecutively

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

In SE Android app v1.0.67, if you tap 'Add comment' on a post, then press the same button on a different post (in the same Q&A thread, without pressing 'Back' button) without cancelling the comment UI properly, the button on previous post will be gone, and it's impossible to add a comment on that post until you reopen the thread.

Example:

1. Find a thread with at least 2 posts (e.g. 1 question & 1 answer)
2. Press 'Add comment' on the question
3. Press 'Add comment' on the answer. **The button on the question will be gone**
4. Posting a comment or cancelling it properly (by clicking the button on the bottom left) will return the button *on that post*

Screenshot:

[image: the button is gone!]

<sup>(Click the image for its larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I broke this yesterday when trying to debug the issues with crashes when clicking on Add Comment. Oops! On it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantastic catch! This is fixed in version 1.0.68 which is pushing out as we speak. It'll be live when this post is 2 hours old.